# Repeat line range n times

Tags: text-processing

I would like to repeat more than once all lines (from line 1 to line 13) from the *0.txt* file and print the output in a *1.txt* file.

**0.txt:**

```
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import sys\n",
    "file = open('out1.txt', 'a')\n",
    "sys.stdout = file\n",
    "print(foo.bar_bar((x,y), (x1,y1)))\n",
    "file.close()"
   ]
  },
```

The only correlated (but not enough)`command_01` and `command_02` below that I know is

**command_01:**

```
awk '{while(++i<n)print;i=0}' 0.txt > 1.txt
```

**(where n > 1)**

**command_02:**

```
sed -n '1,13p' source.txt > target.txt
```

I tried to find some solution to adapt the `command_01` in order to get several repeated segments from line 1 to line 13 of the *0.txt* file, but I did not find anything for now.

Note: I posted the real text that represents my need, so contextually it is necessary that I can run the solution to the contents of *0.txt*.

For all purposes, considering that I want to repeat n times (n > 1, always) all the rows of *0.txt* comprised between line 1 and line 13, my *1.txt* output file should be something below:

**1.txt:**

```
    {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import sys\n",
    "file = open('out1.txt', 'a')\n",
    "sys.stdout = file\n",
    "print(foo.bar_bar((x,y), (x1,y1)))\n",
    "file.close()"
   ]
  },
      {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import sys\n",
    "file = open('out1.txt', 'a')\n",
    "sys.stdout = file\n",
    "print(foo.bar_bar((x,y), (x1,y1)))\n",
    "file.close()"
   ]
  },
      {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import sys\n",
    "file = open('out1.txt', 'a')\n",
    "sys.stdout = file\n",
    "print(foo.bar_bar((x,y), (x1,y1)))\n",
    "file.close()"
   ]
  },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    ... etc....
```

I wish I could have a solution using AWK, SED, Perl or some regex, not necessarily in this order. If you can not use these tools then it is something I can run in Bash.

**About the chosen solution:**

Running the solution @JRFerguson,

`perl -ne 'if (1..13) {push @data,$_};END{print @data for 1..3}' 0.txt > 1.txt`,

to 13 th line was being printed (at least for my tests) as
`},{`

instead of

```
  },
  {
```

see here my full output [1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1HOf.jpg).

But with this command `awk '{gsub(/},{/,"},\n  {");print}' 1.txt > 2.txt` I have added a further step and then corrected the output at 13 th line in relation to @JRFerguson. Such that 2.txt is as shown below:

```
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import sys\n",
    "file = open('out1.txt', 'a')\n",
    "sys.stdout = file\n",
    "print(subsystem.cause_info((1,2), (4,3)))\n",
    "file.close()"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import sys\n",
    "file = open('out1.txt', 'a')\n",
    "sys.stdout = file\n",
    "print(subsystem.cause_info((1,2), (4,3)))\n",
    "file.close()"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "import sys\n",
    "file = open('out1.txt', 'a')\n",
    "sys.stdout = file\n",
    "print(subsystem.cause_info((1,2), (4,3)))\n",
    "file.close()"
   ]
  },
```

Combining this additional command I consider the @jrferguson response as sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
perl -ne 'if (1..13) {push @data,$_};END{print @data for 1..3}' 0.txt > 1.txt
```

This reads the first 13 lines of your `0.txt` file into an array. Then, the contents of the array is written to 3 times (for example) to `1.txt`.

Note that the `0.txt` file is only read once.

Comment: @JRFergunson Your solution is partially expected but in the output file the Character `]` should not be on the same line as `{` . This I say because my output file using your solution has generated the following excerpt `]  {\n
   "cell_type": "code",` (where `\n` is line break on text file). From what I'm realizing `},` **being deleted in the output file**.

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe.

Comment: see my output 1.txt here https://imgur.com/a/Pwi6tyB  while making `perl -ne 'if (1..13) {push @data,$_};END{print @data for 1..3}' 0.txt > 1.txt`. I am trying `perl -ne 'if (1..13) {push @data,$_ . "\n"};END{print @data for 1..3};'` but this has create line break on all lines to 1.txt instead only on 13 nth line.

Comment: Running the solution @JRFerguson, `perl -ne 'if (1..13) {push @data,$_};END{print @data for 1..3}' 0.txt > 1.txt`, to 13 th line was being printed (at least for my tests) as `},{` instead of `},\n  {` (where \ n is not in the 0txt file but just clarifies that there is a line break there) but with this command `awk '{gsub(/},{/,"},\n  {");print}' 1.txt > 2.txt` I have added a further step and then corrected the output at 13 th line in relation to @JRFerguson. Combining this additional command I consider the @jrferguson response as sufficient.